# Django ArrayField. How to save JSON in array from Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-admin

I have an ArrayField in my model. My model looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(UUIDPrimaryKeyModel):
      canceled_plans_data = ArrayField(models.JSONField(), default=list, blank=True)
```

When I append python dict in this field, it gets saved and later fetched easily. But as soon as I open this model in Django Admin and without any change in any field of this model, click on save button, it gives me error.

Error is following:

```
Item 1 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid JSON.
Item 2 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid JSON.
```

I am not sure what's wrong. I have just shown this field in Admin Model like this:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      fields = ('user', 'canceled_plans_data',)
```

How I can fix this problem?